# Testing iFrameResizer.js on localhost throws error. Host file editing not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-10, localhost, host

I have an external website, which I show in my own website by using an `iframe`. I added the [iFrame Resizer Package](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) and the [Types for iFrame Resizer Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/iframe-resizer) (I use TypeScript) to my `package.json` **dependencies** and **devDependencies** (important: I work locally on my localhost):

*package.json:*

```
"dependencies": {
    "iframe-resizer": "4.2.10"
}

"devDependencies": {
    "@types/iframe-resizer": "3.5.5"
}
```

*iframe.html*

```
<div class="iframe">
    <iframe class="iframe__iframe" src="https://www.my-external-website.com" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>
```

*iframe.ts:*

```
import { iframeResizer } from 'iframe-resize';

export class Iframe {
    constructor(message: string) {
        iframeResizer({ log: true }, '.iframe__iframe');
    }
}
```

My `import` works, my external website has the required `iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js` file, my own website with the `iframe` has the required `iframeResizer.min.js` file. The `logs` from the `iframeResizer()` work. But it does not resize and throws me this error in the `console`: `iframeResizer.js:8 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://something.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.my-external-website.com').`

So I thought it has to be an permission/security thing. So I tried to redirect my `localhost` to the external website by editing my `host file` on `Windows 10`:

*host file:*

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1    https://www.my-external-website.com
::1          https://www.my-external-website.com
```

I got the same error after reloading, rebooting etc. Any ideas how I can test this local?

Comment: For one, take the `https://` part out of your hosts txt file. That's not part of a hostname/domain name.

Comment: @kimbo Good point! Removed it and still not working...any other ideas?